# Setting Environmental Variables In Apache Flink Jobs

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-flink

**! EDIT ANSWER BELOW !**

I have minikube local Kubernetes cluster, and I have deployed [Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator).

Following provided samples in Flink Kubernetes Operator git repository and [Basic HA example](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/examples/basic-checkpoint-ha.yaml) I've deployed my own job.

My job contains

- Kafka source
- Azure Blob Storage file source
- Postgres database sink

So far I have hardcoded all the Kafka and File source, and Postgres sink connection string and settings in my Java job code.

```
return KafkaSource.<Aggregation>builder()
    .setBootstrapServers("...")
    .setProperty("...")
    .setGroupId("...")
    // Other properties...
    .build();
```

**Question**

What approach should I take to pass environmental variables/settings to Flink job? Should they somehow be included in YAML files? Or is there some other way?

**ANSWER:**

Create configMap in YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: flink-configuration-map
data:
  sqlConnectionString: value
```

Then assign it to FlinkDeployment

```
podTemplate:
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: flink-main-container
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: flink-configuration-map
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in this [link](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/helm/flink-kubernetes-operator/templates/flink-operator.yaml#L136) the sample templates of the Helm chart for reference.

Below is sample use of the configmap base on the docs

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: flink-operator-config
  namespace: flink-namespace
data:
  flink-conf.yaml: |
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "flink-operator.name" . }}
  namespace: flink-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: 
          image: 
          env:
            - name: OPERATOR_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: HOST_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.hostIP
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: OPERATOR_NAME
              value: {{ include "flink-operator.name" . }}
            - name: FLINK_CONF_DIR
              value: /opt/flink/conf
            - name: FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR
              value: /opt/flink/plugins
            - name: LOG_CONFIG
              value: -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/flink/conf/log4j-operator.properties
            - name: OPERATOR_KEYSTORE_PATH
              value: /opt/flink/tls-cert/keystore.jks
            - name: OPERATOR_TRUSTSTORE_PATH
              value: /opt/flink/tls-cert/truststore.jks
            - name: OPERATOR_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
          envFrom:
          volumeMounts:
            - name: flink-operator-config-volume
              mountPath: /opt/flink/conf
            - name: flink-artifacts-volume
              mountPath: /opt/flink/artifacts
            - name: flink-operator-cert-secret
              mountPath: /opt/flink/tls-cert
```